# Word/phrase for when an incorrect approach leads to an unexpectedly great result

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

> [Related question on Chinese.SE](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/4924/how-to-say-%E6%AD%AA%E6%89%93%E6%AD%A3%E7%9D%80%E2%80%9C-in-english)

There is a phrase ("歪打正着" in Chinese and "怪我の功名" in Japanese) which roughly means "do the wrong thing but achieve the right result anyway". Is there a similar phrase or idiom in English?

**Examples**:

- (From the related question): The subject brings a gift to a friend but the friend wasn't present. When the subject tried again on another day, the friend was present, but - unknown to the subject - it was also the friend's birthday, so the gift became a birthday gift too.
- When you lose your job/lover but this leads you to find a much better one

Some translations available online are "score a lucky hit" or "hit by a fluke" but I feel these do not capture the incongruity between approach and outcome.

Compare this with [situational irony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony#Situational_irony), which is often used when the aim or intent is good but the outcome is incongruously bad.

Comment: A happy coincidence?

Comment: Related: [Word or phrase for mere coincidence that brings happiness](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96583/word-or-phrase-for-mere-coincidence-that-brings-happiness)

Comment: Related: [Is there a word that means “doing the right thing for the wrong reason”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10466/is-there-a-word-that-means-doing-the-right-thing-for-the-wrong-reason)

Answer (score 8):

For your examples, the word *serendipitous* would fit:

> **serendipitous** *adjective*
>   occurring or discovered by chance in a happy or beneficial way:
>   *a serendipitous encounter*
>
> **serendipity** *noun* [mass noun]
>   the occurrence and development of events by chance in a happy or beneficial way:
>   *a fortunate stroke of serendipity*
>
> [ODO]

Apparently the word is a coinage:

> 1754: coined by Horace Walpole, suggested by *The Three Princes of Serendip,* the title of a fairy tale in which the heroes ‘were always making discoveries, by accidents and sagacity, of things they were not in quest of’